# How do I send a response from a GET request query from the server-side of an express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I am using a query to a postgres db to store the result in a variable in a GET request on the server-side of an Express app.

My query returns the issueID that i am looking for when i run it in psql, but I am having a hard time getting the response to store in a variable so I can send the response to the client side.

My code looks like this:

```
const pg = require('pg');
const connection = 'postgres://aa2:aa2@localhost:5432/bugtrackingdb';

const client = new pg.Client(connection) ;
client.connect();

    app.get('/tracking', function(req, res) {
    var sql = "SELECT bugtracking.issues.issueID FROM bugtracking.issues WHERE bugtracking.issues.issueID = (SELECT MAX(bugtracking.issues.issueID) FROM bugtracking.issues);"
    var issueID;

    client.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if (err){
            console.log("error in tracking");
        }

        issueID = JSON.stringify(result.rows[0]);

        console.log("Tracking Result" + issueID);


        //GET results
        res.json(res.statusCode);
        // res.json(issueID);
        console.log("Selected Bug Tracking IssueID. Status Code: " + res.statusCode);
    });
});
```

How do I get the data from the query to store the data in the issueID variable to send it to the client-side of my app?

I am using body-parser also.

**EDIT:**
It's almost as if the query isn't even executing because I am not able to get my console.log statements to print. This is my front-end code to help understand better:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://139.169.63.170:' + port + '/tracking',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,    

        success: function (data) {

            console.log("DEBUG DONE WITH CAPTURING tacking#: " + data);

            if (data === Number(200)) {
                issueID = issueID + 1;
                $(".trackingID").val(issueID);
            }

        }
    });
    console.log("Window loads & Ajax runs???");
});
```

**2nd EDIT:**

Here are the results of running my query in psql. I am trying to get the number '33' to return from my get request:

```
bugtrackingdb=# SELECT bugtracking.issues.issueID FROM bugtracking.issues WHERE bugtracking.issues.issueID = (SELECT MAX(bugtracking.issues.issueID) FROM bugtracking.issues); 

issueid 
---------
      33
(1 row)
```

AFter a few changes this is what I am getting to print from the back end console.log statements:

```
Tracking Result: [object Object]
Selected Bug Tracking IssueID. Status Code: 304
```

**EDIT (Getting closer):**

I stringified the result.rows[0] from the object returned from my query. I am now able to get the result to print to the server-side console.log which gives me the following results:

```
Tracking Result: {"issueid":"37"}
Selected Bug Tracking IssueID. Status Code: 304
status: 200
```

However, when I uncomment the line `res.json(issueID)` I get an error.

How do I send my JSON object back to the client side so that I can display it as needed?

Comment: your response should be store in result. 
I don't know how your database is built, but you should be able to access all the values returned by the db this way.

What's inside result ?

Comment: my console.log for result is not printing to terminal. thats what is confusing me

Comment: results.rows.length === 0, is the s a typo? Prob not causing your issue, but it caught my eye in your second if statement.

Comment: I eliminated the if conditions in the original get request to focus on the results

Comment: If your console.log statement isnt printing anything then there is clearly something going wrong with the query. Have you tried setting issueID to something random like a string, just to test to see if its sending properly back to your front end? Should be able to pinpoint the area of fault if you try that.

Comment: in psql the query gives me the issueID

Comment: i changed issueID to 'random string' and im getting nothing. anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I am so close to solving this bad boy. thanks for the questions they helped me get closer

Comment: Anybody know how I can send this back to the client side????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.get('/tracking', function(req, res) {
    var sql = "SELECT bugtracking.issues.issueID FROM bugtracking.issues WHERE bugtracking.issues.issueID = (SELECT MAX(bugtracking.issues.issueID) FROM bugtracking.issues);"
var issueID;

client.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err){
        console.log("error in tracking");
    }

    issueID = JSON.stringify(result.rows[0]);

    console.log("Tracking Result" + issueID);

    // TRY THIS
    res.send(issueID);   
});
```